# error when i try to add picture then dont

Tags: excel, vba

i have created a userform for students to be added in with there photos.
when i press on add a picture then i press cancel this message appear:
“Subscript Out Of Range”
and it lights this code:

```
imgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & adminpanel.Studentname & _
     "." & Split(imgSourcePath, ".")(UBound(Split(imgSourcePath, ".")))
```

i think i should add a message to say that you have not added a photo but i dont know how.

Comment: Look for `MsgBox` ?

Comment: Place `On Error Resume Next` before the imgDestination line. Below that line add: `If Err Then Msgbox "You forgot the picture", vbInformation, "Missing picture"`, next line, `On Error Goto 0`

Comment: When user cancel the dialog `imgSourcePath` is nothing so there is no  `UBound` for empty array

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried what you have said but the same

Comment: my code have error message but not working
`imgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & adminpanel.Studentname & _
     "." & Split(imgSourcePath, ".")(UBound(Split(imgSourcePath, ".")))
     
    If imgDestination = "" Then MsgBox "An error occurred", vbCritical, "System Error"`